# Firefox issue span with padding and border

Tags: html, css, firefox

So, I have a span with some text in it, it has padding and it has a border.

It displays ok in chrome and safari, but in firefox it has more space between the text and the bottom border than between the text and the top border. Inspecting the element in firefox I figured out that the span in firefox has more height than the text inside it, and the text is top-aligned. Below is a screenshot to explain myself.

But first, this is the code:

```
span.num{
  border:1px solid #00B288;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding:5px 15px;
  font-size:25px;
  color:#fff;
  font-weight:100;
  letter-spacing: 0.5px;
}

<span class="num">0800-777-8101</span>
```

Chrome: http://puu.sh/lHWSM/aa4e15a522.png

Firefox: http://puu.sh/lHWUv/aa066712c3.png

As you can see in this last screenshot, firefox is making the span take bigger height than it's content. http://puu.sh/lHX1V/c6f6a12c13.png

How can I fix this?

Comment: @HunterTurner it does not work, I tried setting `line-height ` as I saw it in my first research, but modifying line-height only moves the entire span up or down (similar as adding margin-top), but makes no effect inside the border

Comment: Here's a fiddle for testing https://jsfiddle.net/Hunter377/1vc69x2x/1/

Comment: @HunterTurner You can see, opening your JSFiddle in firefox reproduces the same issue I am talking about.

Comment: Ya I can see it, I just made it for testing purposes. I'm messing with it now.

Comment: @HunterTurner Thanks a lot for your time man, I'll let you know if I find the workaround or what is causing this.

Comment: sorry I couldn't be more help. I looked everywhere and tried a lot of different things, but couldn't find an elegant solution.

Comment: I tried with different font-familys and with some it works fine. I guess it is just a firefox bug.

Comment: @pablito.aven, what font-family are you using? Also, are you using some 3rd party framework like bootstrap, etc? That could be interfering with your CSS too.

Answer (score 0):

That is because Chrome and Firefox render fonts differently and also have a different default `line-height`. Setting a fixed `line-height` and setting `display:inline-block` You can force them to render the element with the same rules.

Example:

```
span.num{
  border:1px solid #00B288;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding:5px 15px;
  font-size:25px;
  color:#fff;
  font-weight:100;
  letter-spacing: 0.5px;

  line-height:1.2em;
  display:inline-block;
}
```