# Why does Firefox vertically center text differently to Chrome?

Tags: css

Whenever I am making something like a box with text inside, eg. a button, I notice that I can never get the text to be perfectly centered in Firefox, although it does work perfectly in Chrome. I have tried multiple different fonts, using different CSS resets and methods of centering, but it seems to be that in Firefox text just isn't actually centered inside its own content box.

Firefox: [firefox demo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jvUqa.png)
Chrome: [chrome demo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dcSvg.png)

CSS:

```
span {
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    font-size: 48px;
}
```

Does anyone know why this might be the case, and if anything can be done to fix it?
Thanks

Edit: jsfiddle link to test https://jsfiddle.net/b4zwLgck/1/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Firefox issue span with padding and border](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34070838/firefox-issue-span-with-padding-and-border)

Comment: Unfortunately not, I tried adding a fixed line height and display: inline-block, but I get the same result. Although I'm pretty sure the poster of that question was experiencing the same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found that this is a bug specific to Firefox for MacOS, in which the text content box does not leave space above the text for diacritics, contrary to basically every other browser. I found a bug report on bugzilla that is over 14 years old(!) describing this problem, with the latest comment confirming it to still exist as of four months ago. I have submitted a new bug report, so hopefully this gets fixed.

Comment: Hi, Wolfang. Do you have a link to this Bug Report on Bugzilla that you could share? Thank you.